# How to compare user input to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I want to make a bash script that asks for input but this doesn't work.

```
Echo "Enter code A1"
Read A1

if [[ "$A1" == "1" ]]
then
    echo "Accepted"
else
    echo "Sorry but that is wrong"
fi
```

I am always getting the wrong string even if I answer 1

Comment: `Echo` and `Read` are not valid commands

Comment: How are you running this script? It seems to be missing a valid `#!`-line. Also, command names are case-sensitive, and the `read` command has `-p` for using a prompt (removing the need for that first `echo`, which should have gone to standard anyway error since it's a prompt).

Comment: If one were to run that exact script, it would indeed print "Sorry but that is wrong". It would also print errors about the first two commands. Those should be the first thing to deal with. Now, if your script doesn't happen to be exactly the one you posted, then it's rather difficult for anyone to give useful advice.

Comment: Loose the first 2 lines and replace them both with: read -p "Enter code A1: " A1

Comment: Change the line containing the if with: if [ "$A1" = "1" ];

Comment: And change the line:  echo "Accepted" with: echo "Accepted: $A1".

Comment: Oh thank yall for the good help. I will be sure to make use of it.

Comment: @CinaedSimson, why change `[[` to `[`? The question is tagged [tag:bash], and the if statement in the question is valid bash syntax.